# Why am I getting "400 Bad Request" for this URL in Spring MVC?

Tags: spring, datetime, spring-mvc, iso

The following URL results in a "400 Bad Request":

`http://localhost:8080/springdata_web/rest/errors/test?from=2014-05-25T00:00:00.000Z&to=2014-05-27T00:00:00.000Z`

The matching `@RequestMapping` is below.  I can see I am definitely hitting this method because I see the Sysout line in the console using the following URL for example:

`http://localhost:8080/springdata_web/rest/errors/test?from=&to=`

So I guess it's to do with the `Date` type and Spring not accepting the format I'm passing in the request params but I don't see why.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/test",
        method = RequestMethod.GET,
        produces = "application/json")
@ResponseBody
public Resource<List<ErrorsDTOEntity>> getAllErrors(
        @RequestParam(value = "from", required = true) @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE_TIME) Date from, 
        @RequestParam(value = "to", required = true) @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE_TIME) Date to) {
    System.out.println("getAllErrors(Date, Date);");
    List<ErrorsDTOEntity> services = errorsDAO.getAllErrors(from, to);
    Resource<List<ErrorsDTOEntity>> toReturn = new Resource<List<ErrorsDTOEntity>>(services);
    toReturn.add(linkTo(methodOn(ErrorsController.class).getAllErrors(from, to)).withSelfRel());
    return toReturn;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was the format of the date in the URL.  This URL-encoded request works:

`http://localhost:8080/springdata_web/rest/errors/test?from=2014-05-25T00%3A00%3A00.000%2B0000&to=2014-05-27T00%3A00%3A00.000%2B0000`

Answer (score 0):

The date pattern you are passing for ( from / to) is not matching. Underltying  pattern for  is **DateTimeFormat.ISO DATE_TIME**:

> yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss.SSSZ

so example time is as below :

**2000-10-31T01:30:00.000-05:00**

try whether following request work:
test?from=2000-10-31T01:30:00.000-05:00&to=2000-10-31T01:30:00.000-05:00

Spring Docs says :

[image]

Comment: @conorgriffin - Can you please belowsample time -    
2011-07-11T21:28:59.564+01:00

Comment: T is added there instead of space